# Unable to access binding information for class

Tags: java, maven, jibx

I know this question has been asked over and over again, and its always an Eclipse Maven JIXB problem. I don't think it has ever been resolved.

When I try to test my code I get the following error

```
Unable to access binding information for class com.generated.xml.addbooking.Request
Make sure the binding has been compiled
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: JiBX_bindingList
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1882)
    at org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getBindingList(BindingDirectory.java:68)
```

Now I have generated the POJOs and have generated a binding.xml file using the following POM.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>schemata-a</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaLocation>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaLocation>
        <includeSchemas>
          <includeSchema>AddBookingRequest.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
        <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java</schemaBindingDirectory>
        <includeSchemaBindings>
          <includeSchemaBindings>binding.xml</includeSchemaBindings>
        </includeSchemaBindings>
        <options>
          <package>com.generated.xml.addbooking</package>
        </options>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>schemata-b</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaLocation>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaLocation>
        <includeSchemas>
          <includeSchema>SearchHotelPriceRequest.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
        <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java</schemaBindingDirectory>
        <includeSchemaBindings>
          <includeSchemaBindings>binding.xml</includeSchemaBindings>
        </includeSchemaBindings>
        <options>
          <package>com.generated.xml.searchhotel</package>
        </options>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>compile-binding</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>bind</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java</schemaBindingDirectory>
        <includes>
          <include>binding.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

As you can see the POJOs are  generated, the binding.xml is generated but the bind is not being run for some reason?

Comment: Need to add another plugin to make sure maven compiles against 1.5 or above as binding uses generics.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add another plug in that points to 1.5 or above for some reason maven 2 plugins are compiling against 1.3. Was causing the binding problem which uses generics.

I added the following to my plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```